# NATIVESCRIPT - Core (JS) - Switching between TabView and BLANK page

Tags: javascript, authentication, nativescript, tabview

I'm working on an app which is based on TabViews. But if user is not logged in, I wanna show a login screen on app start, respectively the login screen after logout.
The login screen should not be in a frame of the TabView.

TabView is set in **app-root.xml**.

```
<TabView loaded="onLoadedTabView" id="tabView" androidTabsPosition="bottom">
    <TabViewItem title="Home">
        <Frame defaultPage="home/home-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>

    <TabViewItem title="Second">
        <Frame defaultPage="second/second-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>

    <TabViewItem title="Third">
        <Frame defaultPage="third/third-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

I have a **login-root.xml** to load the login page

```
<Frame defaultPage="login/login-page"></Frame>
```

In **app.js**, I wanna decide, if starting "app-root" or "login-root" first.

```
const appSettings = require("application-settings");
let application = require("tns-core-modules/application");


if (typeof appSettings.getString('username') === 'undefined') {
    application.run({ moduleName: "login-root" });
} else {
    application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
}
```

If I now load **LOGIN** first, I run the TabView with **application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });** again. I think, this is not the best way.

How can I load and render the TabView?

I have a **NS-PLAYGROUND** app, where you hopefully can help me. I really appreciate a solution:

**https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=fk1uUx**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply call `application._resetRootView(...)` to replace your root view with TabView or back to login frame as needed.

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=fk1uUx&v=4)

Another options is create new page that includes the TabView and load the page into the login frame.

Comment: **Thank you very much!** That helped me out!